# Arcane Trickster lists the Disable Device skill as tied to Intelligence, is this true?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

On Paizo's website, as well as D20PFSRD, it lists one of the skills for the Arcane Trickster as Disable Device **(INT)**.

Disable Device is normally a dexterity based skill. Is this a typo on both websites, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/prestigeClasses/arcaneTrickster.html

Comment: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/arcane-trickster/

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a copy-paste from the [D&D 3.5e arcane trickster](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/arcaneTrickster.htm), which also had Disable Device as a class skill, except that [Disable Device was an Intelligence-based skill in 3.5e](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/disableDevice.htm) (and [Open Lock](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/openLock.htm) was a separate, Dexterity-based skill, that Pathfinder merged with Disable Device).

Ultimately, the little parenthetical note in class skill lists is there purely to be a reminder, so this error has no actual effect on the game rules; the primary source on this subject is the Disable Device skill description itself, and that says Dexterity.

Comment: Good catch on the copy pasta